# How to get and update height in Healthkit in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, healthkit

I am trying to get and update height from Healthkit but not getting any document for swift 3.

Is there any way to get height from healthKit also to update height in healthKit?

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: I also have same problem

Answer (score 8):

Create an healthkit instance

```
let healthKitStore:HKHealthStore = HKHealthStore()
```

Request Permission

```
func requestPermissions(completion: @escaping ((_ success:Bool, _ error:Error?) -> Void)){
    let healthKitTypesToRead : Set<HKSampleType> = [
        HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.height)!,
        HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyMass)!,
    ]

    let healthKitTypesToWrite: Set<HKSampleType> = [
        HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.height)!,
        HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyMass)!,
    ]

    if !HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {
        print("Error: HealthKit is not available in this Device")
        completion(false, error)
        return
    }

    healthKitStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: healthKitTypesToWrite, read: healthKitTypesToRead) { (success, error) -> Void in
        completion(success,error )
    }

}
```

Reading Height

```
let heightType = HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.height)!
let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: heightType, predicate: nil, limit: 1, sortDescriptors: nil) { (query, results, error) in
    if let result = results?.first as? HKQuantitySample{
        print("Height => \(result.quantity)")
    }else{
        print("OOPS didnt get height \nResults => \(results), error => \(error)")
    }
}
self.healthKitStore.execute(query)
```

Writing Height

```
let height = YOUR_HEIGHT

if let type = HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.height) {
    let date = Date()
    let quantity = HKQuantity(unit: HKUnit.inch(), doubleValue: height!)
    let sample = HKQuantitySample(type: type, quantity: quantity, start: date, end: date)
    self.healthKitStore.save(sample, withCompletion: { (success, error) in
        print("Saved \(success), error \(error)")
    })
}
```

Now if you want to read and write Weight then just use

```
HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyMass)
```

Note: Don't forget to add these permissions

**Privacy - Health Update Usage Description**

**Privacy - Health Share Usage Description**

Hope this is helpful to others who are still searching for it

Comment: I have added height in iPhone's default App Health.But i want to get Height from Health to My Application and I am getting nil value. Can you give me a direction?

Comment: @HimaliShah: I have already mentioned the reading code, but cant help if i cant see the code, Post a question with code that your wrote to retrieve it

Comment: Dude, you are a god!

Comment: I cant read Height in iOS 15.4 Simulator, Xcode 13.3